# Is Django the Best solution for me, if so please help me

Tags: windows, django, web-applications, migration, pinax

What is the easiest (and fastest) way to migrate (+-) a simple data driven "app" to a Framework that does most of the work for me (like forms, add , remove).

What I have is a simple Excel 2003 for Stock managemment.

Quite simple, 3 tables:

- 1 for **Information **on the product.
- 1 with **product code**, **type of movemment** (IN ou OUT), **quantity** and **by who**
- 1 with product code and the actual STOCK on that product

  (I know it could be more optmised.... but I don't think it's worth it)

I was think about using **DJANGO**, but I don't have a lot of background on the matter(are there ways automate the process??).

Is Django better for me? Or maybe **PINAX**(if PINAX, what apps ?? )

P.s this will only be available in a LAN, not the web.

**Evolution:**

I tried to install [InstantDjango](http://www.instantdjango.com/), but I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:\django\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\django-admin.py", line 1 4, in 
>       from django.core import management ImportError: No module named
>   django.core

If anyone knows how to solve this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think django would be great for this.   The documentation is very good which is a huge boost in trying to learn it.  Django has an almost-auto admin interface which may do most of what you want.

Other than the admin interface Django doesn't "do the work" for you, but it makes it incredibly simple.  You may have to define your forms, but it does have the ability to create forms based on your models(tables).

I tried Pinax briefly but it wasn't quite right for my project. I think it may add more complexity than you want for your small project. Others might have more insight into using Pinax.

I was trying to get django setup on windows last night with no luck. So I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a simple DJango server is relatively easy and well [documented](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/). If you're familiar with PYthon (and even if you're not) it shouldn't take a huge amount of effort to get something going. [The Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com/) is an excellent resource if you want to learn or get a glimpse of how easy DJango is to use.

I've no experience with PINAX, but DJango is definitely a good solution in my experience.